# How to set up subdomain on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

A client has an AWS EC2 machine running that used to have www.xxx.com pointed to it. There was a main site at www.xxx.com, and also an admin site at admin.xxx.com. He has now pointed www.xxx.com to another web host, and instead pointed www.yyy.com to the old website.

The main site at www.yyy.com works fine, but how do we get admin.yyy.com up and running? Im no good with server config sad to say.

Regards,

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do, but if you have 'main' and 'admin' running on two separate servers (behind elastic IP), you can easily create `main.example.com` and `admin.example.com` by adding `example.com` nameservers to Route53 and then create an A record for both `main` and `admin`.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingHostedZone.html